# tkinter widget: pass argument to command

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, raspberry-pi

I'm learning Raspberry Pi AND Python, reading the marvelous book *Raspberry Pi Cookbook* (2nd edition) by Simon Monk.

The slide bar in Recipe 10.9 is created with Scale from Tkinter. (I trimmed the code a bit). I don't understand how the function **update** gets the value for its argument **duty**.

Can someone please explain how the implication works here?

Thanks!

```
from Tkinter import *

class App:
    def __init__(self, master):
        frame = Frame(master)
        frame.pack()
        scale = Scale(frame, from_=0, to=100,orient=HORIZONTAL, 
                      command=self.update)
        scale.grid(row=0)

    def update(self, duty):
        print(duty)

root = Tk()
app = App(root)
root.geometry("200x50+0+0")
root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

That's simply how the `Scale` widget is designed to work. It automatically passes in the new value to the given command.